# Save a transformed xml to html

Tags: xml, vb.net, xslt

I've got an XML file with XSL, and CSS layers.  When I view this in IE it looks exactly how I want it to look.  When I try to save the file, I just get the XML document, what I need it a formatted HTML document.

I'm using VB.NET 2008, but I'd rather use an external tool than write more code.  I've tried wget and have gotten the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [command line transformation utility](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2FB55371-C94E-4373-B0E9-DB4816552E41&displaylang=en).  It takes an input of the XSL, the XML and outputs the resulting HTML to a file.

Answer (score 2):

In IE, the transformation is happening on the browser, but the XML file itself isn't getting transformed. This is what you end up downloading.

You can use [XslTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.aspx) in your code behind to make the transformation and serve it up as html.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to do it from IE 8 without using any other tool, you could open up Developer Tools (Tools > Developer Tools). It displays the transformed HTML and you can right click on the html node in the tree and click "Copy Outer HTML". Then you can paste it in another editor and save the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In IE, have you tried the Save As > Web Archive, single file or the WebPage Complete option?  In theory, those methods are supposed to pick up all the "extras" too.